# How to send notification between api and angular 6

Tags: angular, api, .net-core, signalr, azure-active-directory

I’m currently working on a project that contains a api that always returns status 200. So I want to keep the user updated with notification. The user is authenticated with azure active directory. The api is a .Net core 2.0 and the front end is a angular 6 project.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to catch the api called events to send user with notification. You can realize it via two steps below.

Step 1. Create a middleware to catch the api called events. You can follow the offical tutorial [`ASP.NET Core Middleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to write a middleware to filter these request url via `context.Request` and add your own logic to send the event messages.

Step 2. Using SignalR to send messages as notification between ASP.NET core backend and Angular frontend via `WebSocket`. There are many resources introduced how to get started for integrating SignalR with Angular which you can refer to.

1. [GETTING STARTED WITH SIGNALR USING ASP.NET CORE AND ANGULAR](https://damienbod.com/2017/09/12/getting-started-with-signalr-using-asp-net-core-and-angular/)
2. [Real-time applications using ASP.NET Core, SignalR & Angular](https://chsakell.com/2016/10/10/real-time-applications-using-asp-net-core-signalr-angular/)
3. A code sample from MSDN: [The ASP.NET Core 2.0 and SignalR application sample, Real-Time Data Editing](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-ASPNET-vNext-Real-Time-b1d27fe4)

Comment: But how can I specify the user with signalR? Because you need a clientId and shouldn’t that be some what has to work with azure ad